# How to add custom CSS for displaying on mobile screens in WordPress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using BeTheme, a premium Wordpress theme. I edited the CSS and added this,

```
.the_content_wrapper{
  font-size:27px;
  line-height:1.6em;
  padding-left:270px;
  padding-right:270px;
  position:relative;
  font-family:Oxford1;
}
```

This works fine while viewing on Desktops, but while I checked using Inspect Elememt for display in iPhones and other phones, I couldn't read at all. It was fully blank due to the Padding. When I changed the padding to 0, the site became responsive again.

How do I go about correcting it?

I tried installing Custom CSS for Mobiles and Jetpack, but the code I found doesn't work. I do not know what div or classes to use.

Can you all help me? How do I display in the mobile as so it seems responsive.

Thankyou!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use media queries like this:

```
@media (max-width:1024px){
    .the_content_wrapper{
        font-size:27px;
        line-height:1.6em;
        padding-left:0px;
        padding-right:0px;
        position:relative;
        font-family:Oxford1;
    }
}

@media (min-width:1025px){
    .the_content_wrapper{
        font-size:27px;
        line-height:1.6em;
        padding-left:270px;
        padding-right:270px;
        position:relative;
        font-family:Oxford1;
    }
}
```

**N.B. Edit the width accordingly**

Comment: Where should I use them, sir? Just add them to custom CSS? And for devices with different width just change the max-width? Thank-you :)

Comment: Call me Andrew lol And yes, add them to your css file as you would add any other css property. You can change the `max-width` and `min-width` according to your site's responsive behaviour

Comment: So simple, so easy. Thanks Andrew. I simulated it on various resolutions and worked like a charm. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad I could help Dinesh.